# How does the type defination of `promise.all` work well in this case?

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I found this problem when I was doing [a question of type-challenges](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00020-medium-promise-all/README.md).

The following code will fail in the case 3:

```js
declare function PromiseAll<A extends readonly unknown[]>(values: A): Promise<{
  -readonly [key in keyof A]: Awaited<A[key]>
}>

// test
const promiseAllTest3 = PromiseAll([1, 2, Promise.resolve(3)]) 
// except Promise<[number, number, number]>, but got Promise<number[]>
```

But when I change the generic `readonly unknown[]` to `(readonly unknown[]) | []` like below，everything will be ok.

```js
declare function PromiseAll<A extends (readonly unknown[]) | [] /* change here */>(values: A): Promise<{
  -readonly [key in keyof A]: Awaited<A[key]>
}>

// test
const promiseAllTest3 = PromiseAll([1, 2, Promise.resolve(3)]) // Promise<[number, number, number]>
```

I don't understand why adding a constraint of '[]' to generic 'A' will affect the case 3. I can't associate them at all.

In addition, the correct implementation is the standard implementation of lib.es2015.promise.d.ts, which I found in vscode

```js
// lib.es2015.promise.d.ts
/**
 * Creates a Promise that is resolved with an array of results when all of the provided Promises
 * resolve, or rejected when any Promise is rejected.
 * @param values An array of Promises.
 * @returns A new Promise.
 */
all<T extends readonly unknown[] | []>(values: T): Promise<{ -readonly [P in keyof T]: Awaited<T[P]> }>;
```

I found this code is work fine. Because it keeps all types and their positions by converting to Tuple:

```js
declare function PromiseAll<A extends any[]>(values: readonly [...A]): Promise<{
  [key in keyof A]: Awaited<A[key]>
}>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the default inference behaviour for array literals passed into a function, the TypeScript team has choosen to infer *array* types over *tuple* types.

You can see it in the tooltip if you hover over the function call:

```
declare function PromiseAll<A extends readonly unknown[]>(values: A): void

PromiseAll([1, 2, Promise.resolve(3)])
// function PromiseAll<(number | Promise<number>)[]>(...)
```

The type of `A` is inferred as the array type `(number | Promise<number>)[]` instead of the tuple type `[number, number, Promise<number>]`.

This behaviour works fine in most situations, but to type a `Promise.all()` function properly, we *need* to infer the *tuple* type. There are multiple ways to do this and you have discovered two of them in your question.

---

But why exactly do both of these methods infer the tuple type? We can get clarification from [ahejlsberg](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31434#issuecomment-493249223) in [#31434](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31434)

> We only infer tuple types when the contextual type is or contains a tuple-like type

And this is pretty much the important point. `(readonly unknown[]) | []` works because the union in the constraint now contains a tuple type `[]`. This is enough to hint at the compiler to infer a tuple type.

Using `readonly [...A]` also infers the tuple since it is using the variadic tuple syntax introduced in [4.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#variadic-tuple-types). A detailed explanation about inference with variadic tuple types can be found at [PR/#39094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094).

> When the contextual type of an array literal is a tuple type, a tuple type is inferred for the array literal. The type [...T], where T is an array-like type parameter, can conveniently be used to indicate a preference for inference of tuple types.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have roughly understood how it works.
However, I now feel that this is counterintuitive. After all, `[1, 2, 3] extends []` is not true, while `[1, 2, 3] extends readonly unknown[]` is obviously correct, and the compiler still chooses to infer the type that cannot be extended to.

Comment: The presense of some tuple type in the constraint is enough information for the compiler to choose to infer as tuple. Assignability does not matter here. You could also use `["a", "b", "c"]` and it would work the same

Comment: Inference comes first and the assignability is checked afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Basically its the narrow tuple `[number, number, number]` type instead of the widened array `number[]` because adding `... | []` to the type, adds a literal type `[]` to the context in which in the return type is defined, in this case to the Generic `A`.

This is the PR that explains/implements whats happening in detail: [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676)

and your code is a perfect example for the following change introduced in the PR:

> The type inferred for an element in an array literal is the widened
> literal type of the expression unless the element has a contextual
> type that includes literal types.

The return type of `PromiseAll` is defined in the context of `A`. `A` in turn uses a literal type in its definition. therefore it consitutes a "contextual type that includes literal types" preventing the typewidening from tuple to array.